# what does 'this' refer to in Javascript functions

Tags: javascript

I understand the general idea behind the `this` keyword but I'm having trouble figuring out what it actually refers to in practice. For example, in both these example exercises, I guessed the wrong number.

for question1, I said that the alert would be '5', because it is referring to the this.x outside the anonymous function in the function.

In question2, I thought the alert would be 5 because this line

```
var alertX = o.alertX;
```

would bind the value 5 for property x inside the variable o to the new variable 'alertX' which becomes the function call in the next line:  alertX();

Can you explain why I'm wrong?

```
var question1 = function() {
    this.x = 5;
     (function() {
        var x = 3;
        this.x = x;
    })();
    alert(this.x);
};
var answer1 = 3; 


var question2 = function() {
    this.x = 9;
    var o = {
        'x':5,
        'alertX':function() { alert(this.x); }
    };
    var alertX = o.alertX;
    alertX();
}
var answer2 = 9;
```

Comment: `this` is the object *invoking* the method, not the scope where it is defined.

Comment: @32bitkid, so, in the first exampl,e isn't the object invoking the method the outer function, which would suggest that the alert should have been 5?

Comment: I haven't debugged this, but I'm guessing in #1 `this` would refer to `window`, thus both `this.x` are equal to `window.x` - you first set window.x to 5 and then to 3, so the latest update would be `3`; however at no point is question1 or question2 invoked, so there will never be an alert.  answer1/answer2 are variables where you set numerical values, so they'll continue to retain those values :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this covers it pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are good examples of how interesting **this** becomes in Javascript. **this** always refers to the context in which it was *invoked / called*, not simply where it is at that moment! question2 is a perfect example of it.

I'm assuming you are invoking these globally like so:

```
question1();
question2();
```

**In question1:**

You have an anonymous function that is ran after you first set x to 5.  This anonymous function if not set to a variable, inside a function etc, *would* have this set to the global variable of window. But you have it within a function & set to variable question1. So when it runs itself, it sets **this**'s (which is question1 function) **x** variable to 3.

**In question2:**

X is originally set to 9, **this** being question2 in this instance.  Now the part that is throwing you off is that, even though within the **o {}** object you set `x : 5`.  And your alertX function is calling this.x. All of this would lead you to think it will alert 5!  But you are invoking your alert function outside of the **o {}** object, hence the *this* refers to question2 function again!

Comment: FWIW: you have no idea what the `this` is actually set to inside question2. We never see how `question2()` is invoked. (Though it is probable that it is invoked directly and thus `this` is the Global/`window`.)

Comment: Well it doesn't matter in the sense that we know where & how **o{}** is invoked: `var alertX = o.alertX; alertX();` which is inside of question2.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: Not quite right. We can only exclude that it won't alert `5`, but we cannot know for sure it will be `9`. In this case maybe if the question explicitly states that it must be one of the answers.

Comment: Well yeah I was referring that it would imply the previous this.x that was created, in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, when you invoke a method with no explicit receiver `this` is the Global object (the `window` in a web browser).

Similarly in the second case: even though the function is defined on the object, and you are inside another, by invoking the function with `alertx()` the `this` is set to the Global/`window`.

In short:

- For `foo.bar()`, the `this` inside of `bar` will be `foo`.
- For `bar()`, the `this` will be the Global object.

  - *This includes so-called "self-invoking lambdas", i.e. `(function(){ ... })()`.*
- For `bar.call(whee)` and `bar.apply(whee)`, the `this` will be `whee` (because that's what these methods do).

Another example:

```
var o1 = { name:"o1", f:function(){ console.log(this.name) } };
var o2 = { name:"o2" };
o2.gogogo = o1.f;
o2.gogogo(); // Will output "o2"
```

Comment: What about bar.call(whee, woo)? what is `this` then?

Comment: @BeeBand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 0):

Put the following into your browser's console

```
var x = -1, log = function(){ // set up some stuff
if(console) if(console.log) return console.log.apply(console, arguments),undefined;
return alert(arguments.join(', ')),undefined;
},
question1 = function() {
    this.x = 5; // question1.x is 5
     (function() { // anonymous function fires in global 'window'
        var x = 3; // so window.x is now 3
        this.x = x; // this is window
    })();
    log('ans1',this.x,this); // see below
},
question2 = function() {
    this.x = 9; // question2.x is 9
    var o = {
        'x':5,  // o.x is 5
        'alertX':function() { log('ans2',this.x,this); }
    };
    var alertX = o.alertX; // alertX === o.alertX
    alertX(); // being called in global scope

    // to make alertX have scope of question2
    this.alertX = o.alertX; // this is question2
    this.alertX(); // so we're calling from question2
},
a1 = new question1(), // note the new operator
a2 = new question2();
undefined;
```

And you'll get

```
ans1 5 question1
ans2 3 Window
ans2 9 question2
```